# Dúvidas com relação ao uso de listas em c#

Tags: c#

Em minha lista consta 4 itens com o código 711, entretanto eu só quero pegar um item dentro dessa lista, existe uma forma melhor para se fazer isso? Pois quando vou preencher o meu append, ela escreve os dados dos 4 e não somente de 1 item dessa mesma lista. O correto seria preencher desta maneira:
[image: O correto era para vir assim]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo:

```
foreach (Movimentacao mov in listaMovimentacao)
            {
                foreach (ItemMovimento dadosItensMov in listaItemMovimentacao.Where(o => o.Movimentacao.Codigo == mov.Codigo).OrderBy(o => o.Movimentacao.ContratoOperCred.Codigo))
                {

                    strConstrution.Append(string.Format(dadosDetalhamentos, dadosItensMov.Movimentacao.ContratoOperCred.Codigo + " " + dadosItensMov.Movimentacao.OperacaoCredito.DescricaoOperacaoCredito,
                                            dadosItensMov.ValorMovimentoMC.ToString("N2"), sumJuros.ToString("N2"), sumEncargos.ToString("N2"), dadosItensMov.Movimentacao.ValorTotalMovimentoMC.ToString("N2")));

                }

            }
```

Comment: Não entendi, você quer trazer apenas um registro por código? ou apenas do 711?

Comment: Do índice 0 a 3 que aparece na lista todos possuem o código 711, porém só quero pegar o índice 2.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo existe uma forma para se fazer?